# Adding input fields in HTML form for converting to PDF

Tags: php

I am using this FPDF [HTML to PDF Conversion script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script53.php).

I need to add more input fields to be included in the pdf that is generated. In the form I tried adding another field with the name html2 like this:

```
Text 2: <input type="text" name="html2">
```

and made the following changes in the php part like this:

```
   $_POST['html2']
```

In the [html2pdf.php](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script53.php) file the following function:

```
function __construct($_html,$_title,$_author,$_date) {
    $this->html=$_html;
```

was changed to:

```
function __construct($_html,$_title,$_author,$_date,$_html2)
        $this->html=$_html;  
        $this->html2=$_html2;
```

But input type 'html2' does not show up in the final pdf that is generated. Everything else works ok. What other changes do I need to make in the html2pdf.php file?

The code for my form file is as under:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/html2pdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['title']))
{
    $pdf = new createPDF(
        $_POST['html'],   
        $_POST['title'],  
        $_POST['author'], 
        time(),
        $_POST['html2']   
            );
    $pdf->run();
}
?>

<form name="pdfgen" method="post" target="_blank" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

Title: <input type="text" name="title">

Author: <input type="text" name="author">

Text 1: <input type="text" name="html">

Text 2: <input type="text" name="html2">

<input type="submit" value="Generate PDF">
</form>
```

Comment: You can literally see all the HTML tags that are supported by the script you're using. See the `OpenTag()` function. `INPUT` isn't one of them. I don't think that FDPF supports PDF inputs at all.

Comment: I don't get it. In the code above, input text types with names 'title', 'author', 'html' are showing in the generated PDF. Just want to know how can I add more input types like in the above example I have added input text type with name 'html2' but it does not pass on to the PDF.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You've added `$html2` succesfully to the `createPDF` constructor, but you also need to process it, just like the `$html`.

Comment: i've mentioned the changes in my post but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite a basic coding problem, but to answer it I will need quite a long answer. First the changes to the HTML to PDF Conversion script. Replace the `createPDF()` class, in that file, with this one.

```
/************************************/
/* main class createPDF             */
/************************************/
class createPDF {

    function __construct($_title,$_articleurl,$_author,$_date) {
        // main vars
        $this->title=$_title;             // article title
        $this->articleurl=$_articleurl;   // article URL
        $this->author=$_author;           // article author
        $this->date=$_date;               // date being published
        // other options
        $this->from='iso-8859-2';         // input encoding
        $this->to='cp1250';               // output encoding
        $this->useiconv=false;            // use iconv
        $this->bi=true;                   // support bold and italic tags
    }

    function _convert($s) {
        if ($this->useiconv) 
            return iconv($this->from,$this->to,$s); 
        else 
            return $s;
    }

    function start() {
        $pdf=new PDF('P','mm','A4',$this->title,$this->articleurl,false);
        $pdf->SetCreator("Script by Radek HULAN, http://hulan.info/blog/");
        $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
        $pdf->SetTitle($this->_convert($this->title));
        $pdf->SetAuthor($this->author);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        // header
        $pdf->PutMainTitle($this->_convert($this->title));
        $pdf->PutMinorHeading('Article URL');
        $pdf->PutMinorTitle($this->articleurl,$this->articleurl);
        $pdf->PutMinorHeading('Author');
        $pdf->PutMinorTitle($this->_convert($this->author));
        $pdf->PutMinorHeading("Published: ".@date("F j, Y, g:i a",$this->date));
        $pdf->PutLine();
        $pdf->Ln(10);

        // store pdf in this class
        $this->fpdf = $pdf;
    }

    function insertHTML($html) {
        // change some win codes, and xhtml into html
        $str=array(
        '<br />' => '<br>',
        '<hr />' => '<hr>',
        '[r]' => '<red>',
        '[/r]' => '</red>',
        '[l]' => '<blue>',
        '[/l]' => '</blue>',
        '&#8220;' => '"',
        '&#8221;' => '"',
        '&#8222;' => '"',
        '&#8230;' => '...',
        '&#8217;' => '\''
        );
        foreach ($str as $_from => $_to) $html = str_replace($_from,$_to,$html);
        // html
        $this->fpdf->WriteHTML($this->_convert(stripslashes($html)),$this->bi);
    }

    function finish() {
        // output
        $this->fpdf->Output();

        // stop processing
        exit;
    }

    function newPage() {
        $this->fpdf->AddPage();
    }

}
```

Notice that I removed the `$_html` argument from the constructor, after all you want to convert multiple HTML sections, not just one. I've split the `run()` method into three parts: `start()`, `insertHTML()` and `finish()`. I've added the `$html` argument to the `insertHTML()` method. This way you can insert multiple sections of HTML into the PDF. I've also added a `newPage()` method, because you might want to put the second section of HTML on a new page.

Now for your own code. You need to change that to this:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/html2pdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['title']))
{
    $pdf = new createPDF(
        $_POST['title'],  
        $_POST['author'], 
        time()
            );
    $pdf->start();
    $pdf->insertHTML($_POST['html']);   
    $pdf->newPage();
    $pdf->insertHTML($_POST['html2']);   
    $pdf->finish();
}
?>

<form name="pdfgen" method="post" target="_blank" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

Title: <input type="text" name="title">

Author: <input type="text" name="author">

Text 1: <input type="text" name="html">

Text 2: <input type="text" name="html2">

<input type="submit" value="Generate PDF">
</form>
```

As you can see I first create the PDF objects, then I start the first page, insert the first section of HTML, request a new page, insert the second section of HTML, and finally I create the output.
So, it's not that complex, it is just a lot of code. I hope this gets you going again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've followed your advice but it didn't work. To check I removed the html2 and tried only html (your way) but it gives the fatal error "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function WriteHTML() on null". According to your way now the code of my file is this: view-source:https://www.welfarenetwork.org/0exp/case-history.htm and html2pdf code is this: view-source:https://www.welfarenetwork.org/0exp/html2pdf.htm

Comment: @haroon I haven't tested the code, so yes, there's a small error in the code. The FPDF object needs to be stored in the `start()` method so it can be used by the other methods. I've changed that now. However, you should try to understand what the code does, so you can solve these relatively easy problems yourself. If there's another problem, then first try to understand why it happens, then try to solve it, and only if you can't ask me again.

Comment: ok thanks, I try my best to understand and resolve on my own before posting but since I am not a developer and is forced to code to resolve issues, I sometimes can't get beyond a certain level. But that's my headache, thanks for the help, appreciated :)